# Authentication doesn't work in ASP.NET Core application when running using IIS Express

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis

There is an application on ASP.NET Core with standard authentication using Identity. When running through Visual Studio 2019 with the "Solution Name" option, the console opens, the Identity Server starts there and everything works correctly. But when I start using IIS Express, authentication doesn't work and when I enter data, the same login page opens again. The database is used by SQL Server, which is open on the local device. Help me figure out how to make the correct launch of the application using IIS Express.
[Screenshot choosing the launch format in VS 2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZbeO.png)

Comment: Please share your `startup` class.

Comment: My Startup.cs - https://pastebin.com/U4BFESZe